# How to compute a connection in practice?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, connections

I just started learning about Riemannian geometry. I came across the notion of a connection $\nabla$. First, does the connection depend on the metric? If, yes, how does one compute the connection from the metric? For example, if I consider the half-plane $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 : x>0\}$ with the metric $\langle u,v \rangle_{(x,y)}=u^T\begin{bmatrix}1/x^2& 0\\ 0 & 1/x^2\end{bmatrix} v$. Then what would be the connection $\nabla$ associated to this metric (I mean how do I compute it in this case and in general)?

Comment: Check out the [Levi-Civita connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_connection).
In general there are connections which are not compatible with the metric, but if you want a torsion free and metric connection then there is a unique choice.

Comment: I see, but to compute the connection I have to express $\nabla_{\partial /\partial x}\partial/\partial y = \alpha \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \beta \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$?

Comment: I feel somehow I have to use the formula  $U\langle V,W \rangle = \langle \nabla_U V,W \rangle+\langle V, \nabla_U W\rangle$ which in my case would for instance be : $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\langle \frac{\partial}{\partial x},W \rangle = \langle \nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}} \frac{\partial}{\partial x},W \rangle+\langle \frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}} W\rangle$

Comment: Maybe use the [Koszul formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_Riemannian_geometry#The_Koszul_formula) ?

Comment: @lulu, yes thank you. I used Koszul's formula to compute the Christoffel symbols $\Gamma_{ij}^k =\frac{1}{2}g^{kl}(\partial_i g_{jl}+\partial_j g_{il}-\partial_l g_{ij})$